# How do I set a div width equal to a Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a div expand as the user presses a button over and over again.

```
    <script>
            heartClicks=10;
            function love(){
                heartClicks++;
            }
      </script>
```

How can I set the width of the div equal to heartClicks?

```
        <div id="luv"></div>
```

Comment: you mean how to set the width of the div depending on the heartClicks variable?

Comment: Are you asking how to set the div width to the value of a JavaScript variable, or are you asking how to set the JavaScript variable to the value of the div's width? Your title asks for one, but the question itself asks for the other.

Comment: if you want to make the div expand based on how many times the user clicks, you will need to dynamically change the width of the div, not set the heartClicks equal to the width of the div. I made this assumption in my answer. I assumed it was a typo but correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('luv').style.width = heartClicks + "px";
```

Comment: I think you were right though.  I edited his question as well as my answer to fit the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("luv").style.width = heartClicks + "px";
```

Something to keep in mind is you're going to need to reset/reapply the style everytime they click so you might want to stick this in your button click function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var heartClicksElement = document.querySelector("#luv");
heartClicks = heartClicksElement.style.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

@aug's answer is great for standard javascript (make sure you have an event handler). If you want to use jQuery (or if anyone else browsing this question wants to use jQuery) try the following:

```
var heartClicks=10;

$(function(){
    $('#expand').on("click",function(){
        heartClicks++;
        $('#luv').css({'width':heartClicks});
    });
});
```

Try it out with this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iandbanks/TeXfe/).